# Can you install custom kernels on DroidX running CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, motorola-droid-x, kernel

Can you install custom kernels on DroidX running CyanogenMod?

Or does the locked bootloader prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, The DroidX can not run custom kernels.

["It is still impossible to flash custom kernels on the Droid X, but the ROM developer community has matured to a point where they’re able to make great things happen on this phone without having to rely on changes to the kernel."](http://rootzwiki.com/_/articles/rooting/root-it-or-boot-it-droid-x-edition-r164)